# Minimizing the maximum cost of a task-to-machine assignment

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have **m** machines and **n** tasks. There is a m by n cost matrix **A** where **Aij** is the cost of executing task **j** on machine **i**. Each task must be assigned to exactly one machine, but each machine may accept multiple tasks.

My problem is to find the way to assign the tasks to machines to minimize **MakeSpan**, the maximum cost of any one machine.

How might I solve this problem? I considered using the Hungarian Algorithm, but it minimizes the total cost, rather than the maximum cost of any one machine.

Comment: "cost to execute" should be "amount of time it takes to execute"? "Hangerian Method" should be "the Hungarian Algorithm"? It doesn't seem like the Hungarian Algorithm is even applicable here, since you're not minimizing the total cost but rather the maximum worker cost. I guess you already know that, but perhaps it should also go in the question to explain why you're ruling it out.

Comment: "All the tasks are to completed in parallel" suggests that you can't assign more than 1 task to a machine (since then they wouldn't execute in parallel). My answer assumes that you don't mean that -- especially since that would require that m=n. Perhaps you can clarify that too?

Comment: Yes cost is the execution time and we can assign more than 1 task to a machine as they are independent.  for e.g. n=512 m=16

Comment: I rephrased your question to remove the ambiguities. Let me know if I changed the problem into a different one.

Comment: I think reason for not using Hungarian Algorithm is that we can only assign  m number of tasks out of n . Every thing else is fine.

Comment: I disagree -- the Hungarian Algorithm minimizes total cost, not the maximum cost of any one resource, so it not directly applicable. If the only problem is that you have a different number of tasks and machines, the Hungarian Algorithm can be adapted by introducing multiple copies of machines and zero-cost tasks to balance the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can express the problem as an integer linear program. Let `B[i][j]` be a matrix of 0's and 1's with the meaning that `B[i][j] = 1` if we assign the `j`th task to the `i`th machine. The fact that the tasks aren't splittable makes this an ILP rather than an LP -- otherwise we could just insist that `0 <= B[i][j] <= 1`.

We want to minimize the maximum cost of any machine. That's not a linear function, but there's a standard trick to express it as such, by introducing a dummy variable (which in the program here is called `MakeSpan`).

The ILP is this program which has m+n constraints:

```
minimize MakeSpan such that

sum(B[i][j] for i=1..m) = 1 for all j
sum(B[i][j]*A[i][j] for j=1..n) <= MakeSpan for all i
```

The first set of constraints formalizes the idea that every task is assigned to exactly one machine. The second set of constraints is that the cost of every machine is at most `MakeSpan`.

The minimum `MakeSpan` is achieved locally when `MakeSpan` is equal to the maximum cost of any machine, and achieved globally when that maximum cost is also minimized.

To solve the ILP, you can use your favorite ILP solver. For example, GLPK is an open source solver.

Comment: what do you mean by dummy variable and what will be the objective function

Comment: `MakeSpan` is the dummy variable -- it's exists in the program as a kind of trick to work around the fact that we'd like to minimize `max(sum(B[i][j]*A[i][j] for j=1..n) for i=1..m)` but that's not a linear function. The objective function is `MakeSpan`.

Comment: Is minimizing MakeSpan the objective function? How will we define it. I have zero knowledge on LP, ILP and MILP

Comment: You can try learning here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming . That describes LP rather than ILP, but the principles are the same. I've put in quite a bit of work to your question and this answer, so I guess it's time you did some work too :)

Comment: I got the concept of LP and also have the glpk toolkit with Matlab. But I dont know how to use it. Can you help me here .